# Error in pig on spark while executing

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-spark

I'm trying to run a script but I'm getting the error. Here is my script:

```
X = load 'hdfs://localhost:54310/testing/abcd.txt' USING PigStorage('\t')AS(user,time,query);
Y = LIMIT X 10;
dump Y;
```

This is the error I'm getting while executing the above script.

```
2014-06-15 14:31:42,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Failed to run saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile at StoreConverter.java:58
2014-06-15 14:31:42,491 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2043: Unexpected error during execution.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910260/pig-beginners-example-unexpected-error which has the same error code and an explanation of what caused it

Comment: I have seen that post as well,I have hadoop installed and namenode and datanode running. Still I'm getting the same error.. Could you please help me out...